# React компонент нужно сбросить счётчик рендеров в дочернем компоненте вызывая функцию из родителя

Tags: reactjs, redux

пишу компонент корзины. Изначально на странице она скрыта, при нажатии на иконку. У неё есть анимация появления, которая отрабатывает только при первом рендере компонента, это сделанно засчёт обычной переменной счётчика. Это сделано из за того, что в корзине есть возможность менять состояние стора, удаляя из него элемент корзины, это вызывает перерендер и с помощью посчитанного количества ренедров скрипт понимает вешать анимацию или нет.Ещё в компоненте есть кнопка, которая вызывает функцию, которая обнуляет счётчик рендеров и размонтирует корзину, так при следующем открытии корзины анимация снова отработает. Но так же в родительском компоненте есть кнопка открытия корзины при клике на которую, когда корзина открыта, счётчик так же должен обнулится, а корзина размонтироваться. Сейчас я вижу два пути разрешения, либо найти какой то способ который будет более правильным вместо обычной переменной счётчика. Либо прокидывать через реф функцию в родительский компонент, что является плохим дизайном.
Прилагаю картинки
[image: Код родительского компонента]
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[image: Код дочернего компонента корзины]

Comment: Ещё не понимаю почему, при изменении стора, элемент размонтируется. Ведь, просто обновляется состояние. я пробовал через useEffect(()=>{
return ()=>{
 renderCount = 0;
}
},[])
но этот код привёл к тому что при каждом удалении элемента корзины, сбрасывался счётчик, и анимация отрабатывала. Что не ожидаемое мной поведение